# Pause and resume a thread from another thread in a multi threaded environment in C++ technical suggestions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to practice in a multi threading environment and I would like to create a program for an imaginary scenario when the program cyclically save the produced data to prevent data loss into a file in case of a crash. So basically in a multi threaded environment one thread is saving data cyclically into a file and when a crash happens and the program is restarted it will load back the data from this file and can keep going. So I am wondering what direction should look into? I am also wondering about design patterns regarding this matter.

Also I would like to pause this cyclical save thread from another thread, but leave the other threads going, for like a scenario when a shutdown is happening in the program to not save the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends entirely on what exactly your program is doing, what the data looks like, etc. If the "produced data" are immutable chunks and you can recover your state from a sequence of such chunks, you can use any form of message passing between the producer threads and the persistence thread to queue chunks to persist. The choice of message passing method would depend on desired performance characteristics, simplicity, etc. If on the other hand what you want to persist is a shared mutable state, then you will need to utilize some locking to get a consistent snapshot of the state to persist.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`std::conditional_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is what you need

Example:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable suspend_cv;
std::atomic<bool> enabled = true;

void SaveDataThread()
{
    while (enabled)
    {
         // wait for signal from other thread
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
         suspend_cv.wait(lock);

         // do save the data
         if (enabled)
         {
             ...
         }
    }
}

void SomeOtherThread()
{
    // a moment to save the data
    suspend_cv.notify_one();

    // a moment to exit
    enabled = false;
    suspend_cv.notify_one();
}
```